# Smartlook doesn't save User consent properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tracker

I am trying to implement Smartlook into our website. We're using React, so I can't directly do what the docs suggest:
https://smartlook.github.io/docs/web/gdpr/

We initialize Smartlook via a script tag in the index.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      window.smartlook ||
        (function(d) {
          var o = (smartlook = function() {
              o.api.push(arguments);
            }),
            h = d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
          var c = d.createElement("script");
          o.api = new Array();
          c.async = true;
          c.type = "text/javascript";
          c.charset = "utf-8";
          c.src = "https://rec.smartlook.com/recorder.js";
          h.appendChild(c);
        })(document);
      smartlook("init", "somerandomstring");
    </script>
```

I show the user on mount a Modal where he can opt-in and when he does, this function gets triggered:

```
setCookie = accept => {
    const consentText = "Blabalbal";

    this.setState({ showModal: false });
    const date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + 360 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    const expires = `expires=${date.toUTCString()}`;
    document.cookie = `acceptTracking=${accept};${expires};path=/`;
    window.smartlook("consentIP", accept ? consentText : false);
    window.smartlook("consentAPI", accept ? consentText : false);
    console.log(window.smartlook);
    if (accept) {
      ReactPiwik.push(["rememberConsentGiven"]);
    }
  };
```

According to the docs, this.should create a property called consent. Initially, the logged object looks like this:
[image: console.log of the initial smartlook object]
Unfortunately, the property exists, but not on consent. After the execution of my function, the whole smartlook object looks like this:
[image: wrong properties]
So it saved the data, just not on the right place, which makes it pretty much worthless for me. Anybody an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the recording has not been initiated.
Before the recording is started, all api calls are saved in the array to be processed after.

You code should work properly once the server responds with a success for the init request.

Comment: We initialized in the index.html. I will edit my original post to clarify this.

Comment: Yeah. there is script initialization and then there are requests to the servers. After the requests to servers are successfull, then the consent is saved.

It looks like yours recording has not been started thus consent not saved.

Comment: What is content of your Local storage on the page with the script?

And as I said before, if the recording does not start (bad response from server, parallel limit, etc...), smartlook object does not get initialized.

Based on the screenshots, recording did not start.

Try opening the page in anonymous window and look at the results of the /check and /init requests.